# Use cases in operations in VDM++

Tags: case-statement, vdm++

Im pretty new to VDM++ and im trying to use cases in a operation to see how it works.

My idea was to give the operation an input and see what it gave me as output. So fx. my input could be:  and I would expect output to be Even.

The following operations fails and give me the error "Unexpected token in expression"

```
public sign: (seq of char) ==> (seq of char)
sign(sign) ==
cases sign:
    <Even> -> "Even",
    <Odd> -> "Odd",
    others -> "Unknown"
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully the error is actually `Unexpected token in statement` (not expression?). The cases statement requires the RHS of each case clause to be a statement. So you would have to say `-> return "Even"`. Alternatively, you can say `return cases sign: ...`, turning it into one large return statement, where the cases *expression* that followed it would then be correctly formed.

Comment: PS. You'll get "Pattern cannot match" errors if you make the changes above, but hopefully the reason is obvious :)